# What is the mkString equivalent in PySpark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am converting a dataframe into a pipe separated values and writing it to a file in Spark shell (scala).  But I am clueless on the PySpark side. Would appreciate some help.

Especially I dont know how to join each columns with a '|'

Here is a scala version

```
scala> val stgDF = spark.read.table("tbl")
stgDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, num: int]

scala> stgDF.map(line => line.mkString("|")).take(2) //How do I do in PySpark?
res0: Array[String] = Array(spark|2001, yarn|2002)

scala> val tmp = stgDF.map(line => line.mkString("|")).rdd
tmp: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[20] at rdd at <console>:25

scala> tmp.saveAsTextFile("stgDF")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
stgDF.rdd.map(lambda line: "|".join([str(x) for x in line]))
```

**Explanation:**

`'|'.join` is the equivalent of the `mkString` in Scala-it takes a list as argument and then joins elements of the list with the delimiter being `'|'`. The list comprehension `[str(x) for x in line]` is just to cast all elements of line to string before concatenation.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: hope that helps

Comment: The above only capture a _subset of_ `mkString` which has three parameters: `(start,join,end)` .  As usual `python` lags `scala`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more compact one and understandable as well:

```
stgDF.rdd.map(lambda x: "|".join(map(str,x)) )
```

Works perfectly for me. 
And to save as a text file:

```
stgDF.rdd.map(lambda x: "|".join(map(str,x)) ).saveAsTextFile("outputFile")
```